# How to move system time to coprocessor1 correctly?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

In MARS mips I get current time with:

```
li $v0, 30
syscall
```

Then I try to move the system time which is 64 bit to coprocessor1 to do some calculation on the number:

```
mtc1.d $a0, $f0
```

The problem is in the inspector on the right it shows me that the double value in $f0 is something else than I was expecting.
If I take the hex and convert it to decimal using Google, the result is different than  what MIPS shows when I change to decimal view. I know for a fact that Google is correct, so I don't move the data correctly?
How to correctly move the system time in coprocessor1 to do arithmetic on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.ece.lsu.edu/ee4720/2016/lfp.s.html, `mtc1.d` just moves copies the integer bit-pattern.

You have to use `cvt.d.w  $f0, $f0` to convert that bit-pattern in `$f0` from `int` to `double`.

They give an example:

```
    addi $t1, $0, 1    # Integer 1
    mtc1 $t1, $f1
    cvt.s.w $f1, $f1      # $f1 = single-precision float 1.0
    add.s $f3, $f1, $f2   # FP add to $f2
```

If you have a 64-bit timestamp in two 32-bit halves, you're going to have to convert it in 2 parts and add, or combine into a 64-bit integer in an FP register if MIPS has an instruction for that.  Or is `mtc1.d` copying a 64-bit integer register?  (I haven't used MARS, I wasn't sure if it only emulated classic MIPS, or if it emulated 64-bit MIPS III or whatever revision of the ISA 64-bit was added.)

Comment: I managed to do it by doing the calculations using some 64 subroutines I created. I only needed to add and subtract to calculate time difference. But you were right on the conversion part. Once I did the calculations, when I moved to float registers I needed to convert the value to doubles.

Comment: @Romeo: You mean you just used 64-bit integer math?  That sounds sensible.  `double` can't exactly represent every possible 64-bit integer, only up to 2^53.  Beyond that, the distance between two representable `double` is 2, then 4, then 8, as the exponent field grows.

Comment: Basically yeah. That was actually another problem I had: i was moving the value returned by the system time into the double, which was to large for MIPS to see it correctly. But if I moved only the time difference, it was seen ok because this was actually at a reasonable size (I presume this means that it was < 2^53).